# find does not work in on focusout method

Tags: jquery

```
$('.gradeX').on("focusout","input.musteri_no",function(){
    var deger = "musteri_no=" + $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'musteri_script.php',
        data: deger,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(cevap) {
            if (cevap.ok) {
                $(this).find("#ts").val(cevap.ok.TS);
                $(this).find("#ts").attr("readonly", true);
            } else {
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here html :

```
<tr class="odd gradeX" style="font-size:12px;">
                    <td style="width:75px;"><select name="tahsilat_turu[]" class="form-control mb15 tahsilat_turu">
                    <option value = "-1">Tahsilat Türü Seçin</option>
                    <option value = "0">Kredi Kartı </option>
                    <option value = "1"> Nakit </option>
                    <option value = "2"> Çek </option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="belge_no[]" value="" class="form-control" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="musteri_no[]" value="" class="form-control musteri_no" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="musteri_unvani" name="musteri_unvani[]" value="" class="form-control" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="ts" name="ts[]" value="asd" class="form-control" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="bolge[]" value="" class="form-control" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="tutar[]" value="" class="form-control" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="tahsilat_tarihi[]" value="" class="form-control datepicker" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="banka[]" id = "banka" value="" class="form-control" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="sube[]" id = "sube" value="" class="form-control" /></td>
                    <td><select name="banka_hesap_no[]" id="banka_hesap_no" style="width:90px;" class="form-control mb15">
                    <option value="-1">Banka Hesap Numarası</option>
                        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($hesapNumaraları); $i++) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $hesapNumaraları[$i]["hesap_no"]; ?>"><?php echo $hesapNumaraları[$i]["hesap_no"]; ?></option>
                        <?php }//for ?>
                    </select></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="vade[]" id = "vade" value="" style="width:40px;" class="form-control" /></td>
                </tr>
```

I can access if i write `$("#ts").val(cevap.ok.TS);`
but i create more `tr` dynamically, like this :

```
$.ekle = function() {
        $("#tbody").append("<tr class='odd gradeX' style='font-size:12px;'><td style='width:75px;'><select name='tahsilat_turu[]' class='form-control mb15 tahsilat_turu'><option value = '-1'>Tahsilat Türü Seçin</option><option value = '0'>Kredi Kartı </option><option value = '1'> Nakit </option><option value = '2'> Çek </option></select></td><td><input type='text' name='belge_no[]' value='' class='form-control' /></td><td><input type='text' name='musteri_no[]' value='' class='form-control' /></td><td><input type='text' id='musteri_unvani' name='musteri_unvani[]' value='' class='form-control musteri_no' /></td><td><input type='text' id='ts' name='ts[]' value='' class='form-control' /></td><td><input type='text' name='bolge[]' value='' class='form-control' /></td><td><input type='text' name='tutar[]' value='' class='form-control' /></td><td><input type='text' name='tahsilat_tarihi[]' value='' class='form-control datepicker' /></td><td><input type='text' name='banka[]' id = 'banka' value='' class='form-control' /></td><td><input type='text' name='sube[]' id = 'sube' value='' class='form-control' /></td><td><select name='banka_hesap_no[]' id='banka_hesap_no' style='width:90px;' class='form-control mb15'><option value='-1'>Banka Hesap Numarası</option> <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($hesapNumaraları); $i++) { ?>     <option value='<?php echo $hesapNumaraları[$i]['hesap_no']; ?>'><?php echo $hesapNumaraları[$i]['hesap_no']; ?></option>    <?php }//for ?></select></td><td><input type='text' name='vade[]' id = 'vade' value='' style='width:40px;' class='form-control' /></td></tr>"); 
    }
```

I can access from `live select changed` to different input, like this :

```
$(".gradeX").live("change", 'select[class=tahsilat_turu]' , function() {
        var secilen = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        if (secilen == "0") {
            $(this).find("#banka").attr("readonly", false);
            $(this).find("#sube").attr("readonly", true);
            $(this).find("#banka_hesap_no").attr("readonly", true);
            $(this).find("#vade").attr("readonly", true);
        } else if (secilen == "1") {
            $(this).find("#banka").attr("readonly", true);
            $(this).find("#sube").attr("readonly", true);
            $(this).find("#banka_hesap_no").attr("readonly", false);
            $(this).find("#vade").attr("readonly", true);
        }else if (secilen == "2") {
            $(this).find("#banka").attr("readonly", false);
            $(this).find("#sube").attr("readonly", false);
            $(this).find("#banka_hesap_no").attr("readonly", true);
            $(this).find("#vade").attr("readonly", false);
        }       
    });
```

But i couldn' t access `#ts` in **focusout**, i can access in **change**
How can i access, when the musteri_no focusout, which ts' s musteri_no ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `success` callback function sets `this` equal to the Ajax Event. An easy workaround is to create a variable to save the previous context:

```
$('.gradeX').on("focusout","input.musteri_no",function(){
    // Store `this` and retrieve containing object
    var $this = $(this);
    var $gradeX = $this.closest(".gradeX");
    var deger = "musteri_no=" + $this.val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'musteri_script.php',
        data: deger,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(cevap) {
            // Use containing object to find #ts
            if (cevap.ok) {
                $gradeX.find("#ts").val(cevap.ok.TS);
                $gradeX.find("#ts").attr("readonly", true);
            } else {
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Dauezevy I modified my code. The `#ts` element is not contained within `"input.musteri_no"`, so one solution is to find a common parent element (like `.gradeX`) and use that.